# django-registration "registery isn't ready yet" error

Tags: python, django, python-3.3, django-registration

I'm using Python 3.3, Django 1.6, and Django-registration 1.1

I installed django-registraiton using setup.py. I placed

```
     INSTALLED_APPS = (
     'django.contrib.auth',
     'django.contrib.sites',
     'registration',
     # ...other installed applications...
)
ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS = 7
```

in settings.py where it should be

but when I run

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

I get a runtime exception: App registry isn't ready yet

traceback:

```
...
File "...\registration\models.py, line 15, in <module>
    User = get_user_model()
File "...\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py", line 133, in get_user_model
    user_model = apps.get_model(app_label, model_name)
File "...\django\apps\registry.py", line 115, in check_ready
    raise RuntimeError("App registry isn't ready yet.")
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

I looked at the code and saw this comment above the ready check

```
 Raises LookupError if no application exists with this label, or no
    model exists with this name in the application.
```

edit:
After installing cygwin and trying to get it work on there I still get the same error. I'm going to try installing on my desktop and see what happens. Has anyone else even seen this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up installing with pip and it worked fine. I'm not sure why using setup.py was breaking

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have a space on `' registration',`, try `'registration',`

Comment: I wish it were that easy, unfortunately I do not have that mistyping in my code. Also it would of had a missing app error instead of app not ready. Thank you for the quick reply though! I have a suspicion that is has something to do with Windows cmd enviroment. I'm going to trying downloading cygwin and see what happens